# What's the difference between traveling salesman and chinese traveling?

Tags: graph, path, traveling-salesman, chinese-postman

What's the *difference* between [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (TSP) and [Chinese postman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) (CPP)?

For me, both wants go to a destination, and then back.

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_the_differences_between_chinese_postman_problem_and_travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: this is a good article: http://faculty.bracu.ac.bd/~rouf/course/summer06/cse426/TSP_CPP.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is about going to each city once and taking the shortest route.

The [Chinese postman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) is about getting a path from each city to each other city.

E.g., with points A, B, C, and D, the travelling salesman could go A-B-C-D-A, but the Chinese postman would go need a route that had A-B *and* A-C *and* A-D, etc.

The travelling salesman route does not have a direct between each point (in the above example there is no A-C link).

Each city is a vertex and each inter-city link is an edge. So, I think I'm just restating [Xodarap's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443332/whats-the-difference-between-traveling-salesman-and-chinese-traveling/4443605#4443605).

Answer (score 24):

Graphs are made of edges and vertices. CPP requires a visit to all edges. TSP requires a visit to all vertices.

Comment: wait, I think it's the oppostive o.O
I know that chinese = hamilton and postman = euler.

Comment: @Alan: A Hamiltonian path is one that visits all *vertices*. Eulerian visits all edges. I'm not sure what your equivalence is (since you seem to give two definitions for CPP), but this is the correct difference between CPP and TSP.

Comment: I learned that the easiest way to solve chinese thing is with hamilton, and the other with euler.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping it ultrasimple:

The *travelling salesman problem* is about visiting each city *exactly once* while returning to the original city (thus walking along a [Hamiltonian cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html)) and also taking the shortest route among all possible routes that fulfill this criterium (if such a route exists). Finding such a cycle, perforce finding the possibly unique optimal cycle with the shortest distance, is "hard".

The *Chinese postman problem* or *route inspection problem* is about visiting each road between cities *at least once* while returning to the original city and taking the shortest route among all possible routes that fulfill this criterium (if such a route exists). A solution that takes each road *exactly once* is automatically optimal and called an [Eulerian cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianCycle.html). Finding such a cycle is "feasible".

Comment: A better algorithm to generate _approximately optimal_ Hamiltonian cycles: [Computer Scientists Break Traveling Salesperson Record](https://www.quantamagazine.org/computer-scientists-break-traveling-salesperson-record-20201008/)

Answer (score 2):

- [Chinese postman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem)
- [Travelling salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

From a brief read of the two articles (and I never took a course in graph theory, so I could be talking through my hat), it appears that the "CPP" involves visiting all edges, and the "TSP" involves visiting all nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The key difference between the two is:

The [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) can not visit a node more than once. The path produced will consist of all different nodes/cities.

The [Chinese postman/route inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) problem can have duplicate nodes in the path produced (but not duplicate edges). I.e., nodes can be visited more than once as long as you take a different route out than you took in.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just another variation of the pathing problem presented in computer science college courses.

The Chinese traveling salesman problem (C-TSP) is a typical symmetric TSP problem. Its simple description is: Given a list of 31 Chinese capital cities and their pairwise distances, the task is to find the shortest possible tour that visits each city exactly once. The C-TSP is a mediumscale TSP problem, which has (31−1)! / 2 = 1.326 *1032 possible routes.

Comment: I think chinese postman is actually different from TSP in that it requires all edges be visted, not that all vertices be visited. (A la the difference between Hamiltonian and Eulerian paths.)

Answer (score 1):

**Travelling salesman problem:**

Given cities and distance between cities, find the shortest distance tour such that it visits each city exactly one. Visualizing this as a graph and a cost or weight associated with each edge, find the cheapest or least weight tour (Hamiltonian path) such that each vertices or node is visited exactly once. We can think of this as finding all possible Hamiltonian path and then find the best among them. Finding all possible routes is an optimization problem and in [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) means no polynomial time solution exists for this problem

**Chinese postman problem:**

Contrary to travelling salesman problem, CPP requires to find a least cost or minimum weight tour through the graph such that each edge is visited at least once. The problem has a polynomial solution and the optimal solution requires to find a Euler tour through the graph if the graph is Eulerian.

Else modify the graph to make it Eulerian and define a Euler tour. A special instance of the Chinese postman problem is where we don’t need to travel all the edges of the graph, but only some of them (*required* edges). This variation is called the *Rural postman problem* and is NP-complete. In other words, given a graph, find a least cost/ minimum weight tour such that all the required edges are covered at least once, may be using the non-required edges.